# How to make a texture not stretch?

Tags: textures, unity

I have made two textures in Photoshop. I applied one of the textures to the sides (one to each side, in the Unity editor) and the other one to the top and bottom sides. However when I extend the object the texture gets stretched which I don't want.

Is there any way to prevent this? The object is a cube.

I don't want the texture to get stretched if I make the cube larger and I don't want the texture to get shrunk if I were to make the quad smaller.

This is what I **don't** want as a result:

[image: screenshot of the not wanted result]

Comment: This is likely a UV mapping issue where the object in question has been planar mapped and should be cube or cylindrically mapped (or possibly custom, if the cube is a standin for something more complex like a person or a space ship).  Also: your texture will get "stretched" no matter what.  That's how texture mapping works (for a square surface you just can't *tell*)

Comment: @Draco18s I have no idea how UV mapping works, I have not added it, is it something I have to do? :/ Or is it automatic or something? :3 (I'm totally lost... lol)

Comment: It's a pretty important step in the 3D modeling process.  Some applications may have default UV coordinates for simple objects that are good defaults, others might not.  If your modeling program doesn't have any options for UV mapping I use [LithUnwrap](http://www.geeks3d.com/20090303/lithunwrap-free-uv-mapper-for-windows/) myself. Not saying it's great, I'm saying it's free.

Comment: @Draco18s I don't model at all. Just create the cubes in unity and apply a texture which doesn't seem to work very well, lol. I guess I'm gonna need to learn 3D modeling? :/

Comment: [This answer deals with a similar problem in 2D](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111060/unity-tiling-of-a-material-independen-of-its-size/112868#112868) - if something like that would be useful to you, I can show you how to adapt it to 3D. I'll just need some details about how many textures you're using, and the rule for which face gets which texture.

Comment: @DMGregory That's almost what I want to do, except I want to do it for each "side/face" of my 3D cube. (I have no idea how to make that work. :P )