# Change texture settings for each object

Tags: unity

So I'm kinda new to Unity, but I've used it a couple of times before. Here's my issue:

I have two cubes with a random texture applied to them (drag'n'dropped something from the Asset Store). These cubes have different sizes, where one is a square and one is a rectangle. I want to set the tiling size to be different on them (because they are obviously stretched on the rectangle), but when I click on one and change it, the settings changes for both of them.

This is how it looks right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UuOk.png

Is it possible to make these settings unique for each object somehow?

Comment: If your goal is to get a uniform texture density over differently-scaled objects, you can also use a [single material that applies the texture in worldspace coordinates](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/136720/39518). The benefit is that this automatically adapts as you change the models, without creating additional assets & draw calls for each variation. But it doesn't look correct for moving objects and needs special handling on some angles. If you need to handle arbitrary curves you can do this with triplanar mapping, at increased cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Tiling Size** property belongs to the **Material** that you apply onto the cubes. So if you change the material on one cube, naturally it will affect the other which is not the action you wanted. You should create different materials with same texture (**Albedo** property of the material) and set the tiling settings seperately. Hope this helps

Comment: How do I do that, though? I simply find the textures in my assets folder and apply them to the object directly.

Comment: Create 2 new **Material** s in the assets folder. Click the little dot next to the **Albedo** property and choose the texture you downloaded from the opened tab. Do this both for the two materials. And then drag each material onto the cubes. After that you will be able to edit their Tiling settings seperately

Comment: Aah okay, so I have to do that for every single thing I want different? Oh well, that's a lot of work haha. Thanks, though!

Comment: You are welcome! Unless you instantiate new materials via script for any object, you have to do that I am afraid :(