# Unity 3D - Materials are Stretching and Tiling doesn't Help

Tags: unity, c#, textures, materials

I am a programming student working with Unity 3D, version 2018.4.6f1 for this class. I wanted to add some materials to my wall, however, this results in a rather ugly result, because my walls are of different sizes.

[image: Note the brown walls.]

This also happens with actual textures.

[image: Note the red lava.]

However, editing their "tiling" as suggested does not result in something pretty, because the sizes of the objects. (In the shown example, both tilings are x: 3 and y:4.) I can't seem to edit the individual tiling on each object, either.

[image: Tiling is x:3 and y:4. Note the Lava and wood.]

How can I fix this, and make everything look nice? I obviously don't want to create a gazillion of the same texture/material just so I can tile it differently for each object.

Comment: Have you considered [mapping your textures in world space instead of object UV space](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/136720/39518)?

Comment: I can't say I have, no. That seems rather confusing.

Comment: If there's a specific aspect that's confusing you, please edit your question above to identify what part you need help understanding. Without this, we won't know how to help you.