# Best way to add material to mesh map Unity

Tags: unity, textures, mesh

Ok bear with me because I don't know most of the terminology yet. I downloaded an asset for 2D tiling to use in my game so I'm basing this off the documentation terminology. It chunks my 1000x1000 map into chunks containing 10x10 Voxels that load as you move around. This works perfectly so I don't particularly want to mess with this. However since the textures are applied to the individual Voxels they don't look particularly good in a grid shape especially if animated. See below:

[image]

Is there any way to make this look better, either by syncing the animation between cells or applying the one texture to the whole block (although I suppose that will look the same just on a larger scale).

Chunk settings:

[image]

I'll upload any code/settings needed I'm just not sure what is pertinent, I've already tried tweaking most settings to little avail.

Comment: Usually "voxel" would only be applied if the game were 3D (think of the cube shapes in Minecraft) but here you've shown a 2D view. This this just one face of a 3D world, or is your game actually 2D? If so, [your question may be similar to this case](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/112868/39518)

Comment: @DMGregory The game is 2D top down view. The asset I started with is a Terraria clone. I'll look at that answer and see if it helps, thanks!

Comment: It would help if you name & link to the tiling asset you're using. From the picture alone, it's hard to know what it's trying to do. It seems to have assigned different texture coordinate/UV ranges to each quad tile within the chunk - are those meant to be tiles with different materials? What would this look like if everything was working the way you wanted it to?

Comment: @DMGregory Unfortunately I was mistaken it wasn't from the asset store but a [github repo](https://github.com/kvakvs/playable_alpha2) and here are the [textures I'm using](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/55290) both the game and textures are meant for side view but I was hoping to adapt it to topdown. Yes the original game meant for each block to have different materials (some were dirt, some stone, etc) I've been retroactively trying to change that. I just want the full 10x10 chunk to be 1 mat type and find the best way to make it look like an ocean.

Comment: but different chunks can have different mat types.

Comment: To clarify your question, please edit it. We don't want folks to have to follow the whole commend thread to figure out what you need. ;)  Now, if you only need one appearance per chunk, why use this github content at all instead of a simple quad or plane?