# How do I apply tiling and offset to a gameobject instead of material?

Tags: unity

I would like to apply a texture to a plane.
I want to assign a certain offset and tiling to it.

The material has a Tiling and Offset option.
However, I don't want to do it on the Material level.

Why?
The material has 5 different Tiling / Offset options.
To try out different tiling / offsets, I have to change all 5 of them.
This does not seem like a good workflow to me.

Instead, I would to apply the tiling / offset on the game object.

Is that possible?

Edit: I think what I actually need is a possiblity to change the UV of a mesh in a flexible way. I think I have found it in ProBuilder's UV options.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a script that iterates over the material's texture properties and updates their tiling and scaling to match a master value.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

public class MaterialScaler : MonoBehaviour
{
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    public Vector2 tiling = new Vector2(1, 1);
    public Vector2 offset = new Vector2(0, 0);

    private void OnValidate() {
        var properties = new List<int>();
        foreach(var material in GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterials) {
            material.GetTexturePropertyNameIDs(properties);
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(material);

            Undo.RecordObject(material, "Change Shared Tiling/Offset");

            foreach(var id in properties) {
                material.SetTextureScale(id, tiling);
                material.SetTextureOffset(id, offset);
            }
        }
        AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
    }
#endif
}
```

If you really want to pretend this is part of the responsibilities of the GameObject class itself, you could always write it as an extension method:

```
public static class GameObjectExtensions {
    public static void TransformAllTextures(this GameObject gameObject, Vector2 tiling, Vector2 offset) {
        var properties = new List<int>();
        foreach(var material in gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterials) {
            material.GetTexturePropertyNameIDs(properties);

            foreach(var id in properties) {
                material.SetTextureScale(id, tiling);
                material.SetTextureOffset(id, offset);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can now call this with:

```
someGameObject.TransformAllTextures(tiling, offset);
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there no such property for the gameobject itself? If not, do you have any idea why not?

Comment: Because GameObjects are just containers for components, and so they have nothing whatsoever to do with materials. It would be absurd to put a material tiling property on the base GameObject class when that GameObject could easily be a camera or an invisible trigger volume or a manager etc. that has no materials associated with any of its components.

Comment: I've added an example using an Extension method if you'd like to pretend that this is the GameObject's job. 

Comment: Thank you. I have added a screenshot to my post. Is my idea so unusual? In my screenshot you see how I have 2 planes, and I would like to have the same material on both, but on one of them, the tiling should be different. Is that so uncommon?

Comment: If you meant to ask "How can I use the same material on two objects, and use a different tiling on one of them", then that's a different question than the one you asked. It sounds like you may be interested in [Tiling of a material, independent of its size](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111060/unity-tiling-of-a-material-independen-of-its-size/112868#112868). You can also accomplish this with a script like I showed above, simply by making it instantiate a copy of the material for each new tiling rate you want to use.

Comment: Yes, great, thank you! The question that you have linked is what I actually wanted to ask, but I guess your script in this question here will also come handy at some point of time.

Comment: Unfortunately your script freezes the Editor for me.

Comment: Can you explain which script you're using and how you've tried to use it? I have not been able to reproduce that in my tests.

Comment: I have created a new script named "MaterialScaler" and put your code into it. Then I dragged this script onto my gameobject. Dragging it onto my gameobject freezes the Editor for me immediately.

Comment: I've just tested again and cannot reproduce this freeze. What you can try though is commenting out the SaveAssets line, as long as you remember to go to File -> Save Project to save your material changes manually.

Comment: I had used an alpha version of Unity. I have tried it now on a final version, and it works great (even with SaveAssets) thank you very much!