# How to create endless background in a 2d top down game?

Tags: unity, sprites

I have a seamless background sprite, and I do not want the player to be able to reach the edge of the background.

Setting huge width and height in tiled drawmode doesn't sounds like a solution.
[How can I make something like this?](https://gifyu.com/image/e8Ag)

I want the background to appear outside the camera in the direction the player is moving.

I think instead of instantiating and destroying background panels every time I should once create them and then change their position.

Comment: It sounds like you have two valid solutions: making a huge sprite with tiling draw mode, or spawning panels of the image at a time and repositioning them as needed. Where do those solutions fall short of what you need?

Comment: @DMGregory I don't know how to create a script that will reposition panels, that's what I'm asking. Does creating a huge sprite affects performance? If not then I'll just make a huge sprite.

Comment: "Does X affect performance" is something you can answer more conclusively by measuring it. That way you don't have to worry about Internet hearsay giving you the wrong info — you can access the truth of the matter directly.

Comment: You could also attach your background sprite to your camera, and [use a shader to tile the texture in worldspace](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/112868/39518), so it automatically maintains a fixed relationship to the world even as the sprite/camera moves.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to set the wrap mode on your texture in the import settings to "repeat".

Comment: @DMGregory yes, thank you.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, remember to post your solution as an Answer below. Or, if you still need help, edit your question to describe what you need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attached background sprite to camera and then used [that shader](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111060/tiling-of-a-material-independent-of-its-size/112868#112868)

**Remember to set the sprite wrap mode to "repeat"**

Comment: This looks like a link-only answer. You could include additional information about how your solution might work, and a simple guide on how to set it up to address OP's issue.